# Symfony JSON response turns array of objects with only one object into an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api, symfony

My JSON response is supposed to return an array of objects. However, if my array of objects only contains **one** object, JSON turns it into an object instead. Is there a way to always return an array of objects, even if it only contains one object? I need to get the length of my array but this won't work because my response sometimes returns an object which causes .length not to work.

```
$response = JsonResponse::fromJsonString(
    $this->serializer->serialize(
        $e->getControllerResult(),
        'json',
        [
            'groups'     => $apiContext->groups,
            'hypermedia' => $apiContext->hypermedia
        ]
    )
);
$e->setResponse($response);
```

$e is a `ViewEvent`. My controller returns an object which contains passengers like this:

```
-passengers: array:5 [
    "id" => "c90e76ad-43e1-48bc-b72c-07f9cf9942d8"
    "username" => "x"
    "roles" => array:1 [
      0 => "ROLE_USER"
    ]
    "password" => null
    "salt" => null
  ]
```

Comment: Please, provide some code to show how you're building your response. Thanks.

Comment: @DonCallisto added!

Comment: It would be useful to check also controller result. If this is generic for "all" (or some) controllers, I suspect that this discrepancy is in how you're returning result from actions, not as you're serializing it.